# Does anyone know CPPEH_RECORD construct？

Tags: c++, reverse-engineering, construct

I reversed one executable file in which I find the `CPPEH_RECORD` construct. I want to know details about it. But there is no more explanation in google search! Please tell me more about it, or give me some links! Thanks to every body that helps! 
The same question can be found [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37873744/function-of-cppeh-record-constructor).

```
void __noreturn start()
{
  int v0; // eax@3
  char **argv; // [sp+10h] [bp-2Ch]@3
  int v2; // [sp+14h] [bp-28h]@3
  int v3; // [sp+18h] [bp-24h]@4
  char **envp; // [sp+1Ch] [bp-20h]@3
  int argc; // [sp+20h] [bp-1Ch]@3


  CPPEH_RECORD ms_exc; // [sp+24h] [bp-18h]@1

  ms_exc.registration.TryLevel = 0;


  _set_app_type(1);
  dword_403080 = -1;
  dword_403084 = -1;
  *(_DWORD *)_p__fmode() = dword_40307C;
  *(_DWORD *)_p__commode() = dword_403078;
  dword_403088 = adjust_fdiv;
  nullsub_1();
  if ( !dword_403068 )
    _setusermatherr(sub_4011BE);
  _setdefaultprecision();
  initterm(&unk_403008, &unk_40300C);
  v2 = dword_403074;
  _getmainargs(&argc, &argv, &envp, dword_403070, &v2);
  initterm(&unk_403000, &unk_403004);
  *(_DWORD *)_p___initenv() = envp;
  v0 = main(argc, (const char **)argv, (const char **)envp);
  v3 = v0;
  exit(v0);
}
```

Comment: It would help if you would provide more information eg. the reverse engineered code like in the other question you posted.

Comment: It is just a fake name that the HexRays people came up with to represent the undocumented exception handling in the Microsoft C runtime library.  Originally came from Intel, Microsoft could not get a source license to republish it.  Dumped in VS2015, good riddance.  Reverse-engineering the startup code of a C++ program is not very useful, it is just boilerplate, it ought not get interesting until main().

Comment: It is like Hans saying. The `struct CPPEH_RECORD` could be defined like anything. If you have other structures, you may have to know the definition and add that to IDA like it's written [here](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/tutorials/structs.shtml).